# PhantomJS on CentOS 7 is rendering symbols instead letters

Tags: javascript, macos, phantomjs, centos7

I am testing a feature I developed with PhantomJS to generate an image from a html string and on macOS High Sierra the picture generated looks natural like this:

### #

[image]

### #

But in my production server with CentOS 7, the generated picture looks like this:

### #

[image]

### #

I am using the same version of PhantomJS 2.1.1,

This the code I am using:

```
    var system = require('system');
    var page = require('webpage').create();

    var documentTop = '<html lang="es"><meta charset="UTF-8">';
    var style = '<style>table{width:100%;}</style></head><body>';
    var documentBottom = '</body></html>';

    var c = documentTop + style + system.args[1] + documentBottom;

    // system.args[1] is the html that is being passed as argument

    page.viewportSize = { width: 500, height: 100 };
    page.content = c;

    page.evaluate(function () {
    document.body.bgColor = 'white';
    });

    page.render('demo.jpg');

    phantom.exit();
```

I've been testing with or without the `meta charset` but no luck so far.

**Edit**

This is an example of a HTML string that is being sent to phantom

```
<div id="order-details"><h2>Orden de compra</h2><span id="client-name">Nombre del cliente: <strong>Demo 8</strong></span><div id="summary"><p>Resumen</p><div id="summary-cols"> <div class="summary-col"><span class="summary-text">Cantidad</span><span class="summary-value">3</span></div><div class="summary-col"><span class="summary-text">P.V.</span><span class="summary-value">48.55</span></div><div class="summary-col"><span class="summary-text">Total</span><span class="summary-value">$ 1022.00</span></div></div></div><table><thead><th>Cant.</th><th>Descripción</th><th>Importe</th></thead><tbody><tr class="odd"><td>1</td><td>Concentrado de Hierbas Limón 50 g</td><td>317.00</td></tr><tr class=""><td>1</td><td>Polvo para Preparar Bebidas Sabor Ponche de Frutas (bote)</td><td>438.00</td></tr><tr class="odd"><td>1</td><td>Polvo para Preparar Bebidas Sabor Ponche de Frutas (sobres)</td><td>267.00</td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

The same but formatted

```
<div id="order-details">
<h2>Orden de compra</h2><span id="client-name">Nombre del cliente: <strong>Demo 8</strong></span>
<div id="summary">
    <p>Resumen</p>
    <div id="summary-cols">
        <div class="summary-col"><span class="summary-text">Cantidad</span><span class="summary-value">3</span></div>
        <div class="summary-col"><span class="summary-text">P.V.</span><span class="summary-value">48.55</span></div>
        <div class="summary-col"><span class="summary-text">Total</span><span class="summary-value">$ 1022.00</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Cant.</th>
        <th>Descripción</th>
        <th>Importe</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Concentrado de Hierbas Limón 50 g</td>
            <td>317.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Polvo para Preparar Bebidas Sabor Ponche de Frutas (bote)</td>
            <td>438.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Polvo para Preparar Bebidas Sabor Ponche de Frutas (sobres)</td>
            <td>267.00</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: 1. You forgot to include a `<head>` opening tag, it should be right before the first `<meta ...>` tag.

2. Does the content you're rendering (`system.args[1]`) contain any non-standard fonts? What happens if you include `body{font-family:sans-serif}` in the `<style>` section?

3. Not that it should cause the difference you're seeing, but for correctness you could include the HTML5 doctype tag: `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the start of your `documentTop` string (right before the `<html ...>` opening tag)

Comment: @RocketNuts Same issue u.u, I actually have a font-family set, but even with doctype and the head one is still generating the image with those characters.

Comment: @RocketNuts I just edited the post adding more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue and it was related to the fonts installed in the server because my CentOS 7 only had a few ones but not the usual fonts or the ones from Microsoft so I used this link

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/327138/73078

Now I only have a problem with the accents but at least the main problem has gone.